# Is there a way to change a value of a TimeSpan object?

Tags: c#

I'm getting new time values in milliseconds regularly and need it in the form like "00h 00m 00s", so thinking of using **TimeSpan** because it's very simple to use.

TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeValue);

But what I'm worrying about now is GC. I don't think it's a good idea to call **FromMilliseconds()** every time because it seems it creates a new instance all the time.
I need to update the time value in every 0.1 secs or so, so if there's a way to modify the value of the TimeSpan object directly, it can be very useful for my case. Otherwise, I think I need to create a method on my own..

Is it possible?

Comment: `TimeSpan` is immutable, so you need a new one each time.

Comment: `TimeSpan` is struct (value type). It will be placed on the stack.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Value types are not always placed on the stack.

Comment: if you worry about speed, test and measure. Dont guess

Comment: @Jenix a timespan is a struct, that wraps a long value. Nothing more. Even if you *could* change it, you'd still end up copying longs. There is no GC involved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `TimeSpan` is immutable.

You must create a new `TimeSpan` instance if you want to change its value. As you can see from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), all the properties are get-only.

But don't worry about GC! Only worry about it when you actually encounter problems with performance. `TimeSpan` occupies quite little space I think.

Comment: Actually, it wraps a `long` value of ticks. Trying to modify (ie replace) that value would use the same space as replacing the TimeSpan

Answer (score 2):

> ...so if there's a way to modify the value of the `TimeSpan` object directly, it can be very useful for my case. ...
>
> Is it possible?

No, it is not possible to modify instances of `TimeSpan`, it is an immutable `struct`.

> Otherwise, I think I need to create a method on my own..

More than likely you really **don't**.  Are you absolutely certain the performance implication of the existing `TimeSpan` really matter to your application?  Have you profiled your application to verify that creating new instances of `TimeSpan` is causing a performance problem.  And even if *that's* the case (unlikely) are you **sure** your *own* code will be better? The .NET framework is intended to be widely used; while it isn't perfect, it's usually quite good.

Comment: Thanks! BTW what I meant was, creating a method that creates a resulted string directly, not a TimeSpan-ish thing, so it's not about "coding a better method than .NET framework's", it's more about "creating one for my specific case". And as you mentioned, TimeSpan is to be widely used, that means there are times when it feels too much or heavy. My App already has too much overhead so that's why I was worrying about GC. A little bit of increments can cause more frame drops in my game, and IT REALLY MATTERS. Of course, I need to compare them both, as you said.

Comment: You never understand me what I'm saying.. What I need is just a "MM:SS" string in every 0.1 secs, not a TimeSpan or any similar Time-related object. In this case, I might have thought so at first, especially when you are insisting a TimeSpan wouldn't place on the stack all the time. I have to create from a new string from a TimeSpan, so that's why I planned to create the string from the beginning. Why should I create an object with longs in this case? That's why I said it may feel "heavy". You'll also know many string objects themselves already can cause GC.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to TimeSpan and it seemed very convenient so I needed to check if it fits my case. And you keep saying as if I wanted to create a new TimeSpan thing.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like changing the value of an `int`. If you do this

```
int x;
x = 5;
x++;
```

You're never changing the value of an `int`; you're changing the value of `x`.

That might sound like splitting hairs, but it sounds like what you want to do is change the value of a variable that contains a `TimeSpan`, not change an actual `TimeSpan`.

That could take many forms, but yes, you can do it. It looks pretty similar to modifying an integer variable.

```
var t = new TimeSpan(1,0,0);  // One day
t += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); // Add one minute
```

Comment: The problem is, FromMinutes() will return a new instance, so it's about the same overhead in the end. Other than that, I really appreciate about += operator thing. It may be useful in some cases. Thanks!